# How to compute the measure using Riesz Representation Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\phi$ : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a increasing function which is right continuous,
define a positive linear functional on $C_{C}\left(X\right)$ by
$$L(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \mathrm{~d} \phi$$ the right part is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, hence by Riesz Representation Theorem(Rudin Theorem 2.14), we have a positive measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ associated to the functional.

The question is how to compute $\mu\left(a,b\right]$,$\mu\left[a,b\right)$,and $\mu\left[a,b\right]$. I guess it's something related to $V_{a}^{b}\left(\phi\right)$, but I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks，is there any reference？@geetha290krm

Comment: Rudin's RCA has this.

Comment: I’m so sorry that I didn’t find it in chapter two. Could you be more specific？@geetha290krm

Comment: You can look this up at Folland's real analysis, chapter 1

Comment: @geetha290krm ... No, I would say $\mu ((a,b])=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}$You've been given references in the comments but I think it's worth typing an explicit explanation.

Royden's real analysis defines the Radon measure $\mu$ associated to $L$ via an extension from: $$\mu(V)=\sup\{L(f):f\in C_c(X),\,0\le f\le1,\,\supp(f)\subseteq V\}$$Where $V$ is an open set of $X$, $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space. You're asking for $\mu((a,b])$, etc., so I assume that $X=\Bbb R$. Your question needs more clarity on this point...

So I assume $\phi$ is a nonnegative, increasing and right continuous function, and I've assumed $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.

Royden shows uniqueness of the above measure w.r.t the property that $L(f)=\int f\d\mu$. So you can immediately let $\mu$ be the Borel measure defined by $\phi$, i.e. $\phi(b)-\phi(a)=\mu((a,b])$ for finite $a<b$. If you want an explicit calculation:

Let $(a,b)\subset\Bbb R$ be a finite interval. We want to find: $$\sup\int_a^bf\d\phi$$Among those continuous $f$, compactly supported in $(a,b)$, and $0\le f\le 1$. Any such $f$ has support contained in a $[c,d]\subset(a,b)$. But there are $0\le g\le1$ with support $[c',d']\subset(a,b)$, $c'<c,\,d'>d$ and $g\equiv1$ on $[c,d]$, i.e. $g$ dominates $f$ and $g$ is a "bump"-extension of an indicator function. So the supremum must be a limit of the integrals of such $g$, as $[c,d]$ is enlarged to approach $(a,b)$. The contributions of the vanishing aspects of $g$, as it tends to $0$ sharply from $1$ on $(d,b)$ and $(a,c)$, will vanish as $d\to b,\,c\to a$. It follows that the supremum is the supremum of $\int_c^d g\d\phi$, i.e. the supremum of $\phi(d)-\phi(c)$, which is $\phi(b^-)-\phi(a)$.

So $\mu((a,b))=\phi(b^-)-\phi(a)$ for finite open intervals $(a,b)$. Now you want to find the measure of $(a,b]$ for finite $a<b$.

As the extension of $\mu$ is Radon, I know $\mu((a,b])$ is the infinimum of $\mu((a,b'))$ for all $b'>b$. That is, $\inf_{b'>b}[\phi(b'^-)-\phi(a)]$, which is simply $\phi(b)-\phi(a)$.

In case it's confusing, I might explicitly define $g$ like this. Given $a<c'<c<d<d'<b$, I let $g\equiv1$ on $[c,d]$ and I let $g\equiv0$ on $(a,c')$ and $(d',b)$. I then let $g$ continuously decrease to $0$, from $1$, on the intervals $[d,d']$ and $[c',c]$, e.g. via a straight line extension. You can make $g$ smooth if you wish.